# Spring REST Error - Error to get data from response

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am using SpringBoot Java 11 and have a REST endpoint:

**REST Service**

```
   @Operation(summary = "Endpoint called by the UI to get the journal entries (using the posted form)")
    @PostMapping(path = "/journal-entries/{memberId}/{firstRow}/{noRows}/{overrideFilterForMerchants}")
    public ResponseEntity<PowWowControllerDTO> getEntries(@RequestBody PowWowDashboardDTO powWowDashboardDTO, @Parameter(description="memberId") @NotBlank @PathVariable final Long memberId, @Parameter(description="first row") @NotBlank @PathVariable final int firstRow, @Parameter(description="no rows") @NotBlank @PathVariable final int noRows, @Parameter(description="has override role") @NotBlank @PathVariable final boolean overrideFilterForMerchants) {
        PowWowControllerDTO dto = new PowWowControllerDTO();
        try {
            dto = powWowJournalService.getJournalEntries(powWowDashboardDTO, memberId, firstRow, noRows, overrideFilterForMerchants);
            dto.setStatus("Success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            dto.setStatus("Error: "+e.getMessage());
            logger.error("Exception in REST endpoint: getEntries", e);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity(dto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

When this endpoint is called, in debug, I can see that the `PowWowControllerDTO` is populated as expected.

I have an old Struts Java 7 application that needs  to consume the above endpoint:

**REST Client**

```
                PowWowControllerDTO dto = new PowWowControllerDTO();
                String jsonString = response.getText();
                if (jsonString != null) {
                    logger.info(jsonString);
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    dto = gson.fromJson(jsonString, PowWowControllerDTO.class);
```

This gets an exception trying to convert the response to a DTO.

**Error**

> Error to get data from response:
> com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected EOF at line 1
> column 48448

I can see from the `jsonString` that there is a response which looks  like a number of empty objects, that does contain:

> "message":"Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion
> (StackOverflowError); nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite
> recursion (StackOverflowError)

**PowWowControllerDTO**

```
public class PowWowControllerDTO {

    private List<PowWowJournalEntities> journals = new ArrayList<>();
    private int firstRow;
    private int lastRow;
    private Long noRows;
    private String status;
```

**PowWowJournalEntities**

```
public class PowWowJournalEntities {

    private PowWowJournalHeaderEntity powWowJournalHeaderEntity;
    private List<PowWowTransactionEntity> powWowTransactionEntities = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<PowWowAuditTrailEntity> powWowAuditTrailEntities = new ArrayList<>();
    private PowWowJournalEntryObjectEntity powWowJournalEntryObjectEntity;
```

**PowWowJournalHeaderEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "powwowjournalheader")
public class PowWowJournalHeaderEntity {
```

Comment: How your PowWowControllerDTO  class looks like?

Comment: Please show the sample of body that you get this error with. And also having an idea of what's inside PowWowControllerDTO could help better

Comment: I have added the info you requested. is the problem perhaps that it is returning an `@Entity` object instead of a POJO?